# Is it possible to recover deleted tables?

Tags: ms-access, recovery

One user deleted some tables from the database. Fortunately after that the base was not compressed and did not recover.

Now I have a question. Is it possible to restore these tables, with all the contained data? Sorry if the question is "childish" but although I thought I had seen a similar topic, I searched but can't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything can be done, if not compressed. The data is still in BMD remained. You can to do ms access database recovery viewed them via a hex editor. You can try them and pull at least partially.
If nothing happens then try access data recovery tool as [AccessRecoveryToolbox](https://www.oemailrecovery.com/access_recovery.html)  that can extract information from the damaged file and save it in desired format.

I don't know but maybe this topic on tekhnet somehow be useful to you.
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b7ec7a0a-60ad-4b83-ba86-7c1fe252e89a/mdb-file-completely-corrupt-after-many-attempts-to-recover-it?forum=officeitproprevious

Answer (score 1):

According to [Microsoft's Support website](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Restore-a-database-9bf54570-9b71-42e5-9cec-c4d1881c75c8):

> To restore a database, you must already have a backup copy of your database.

This is true of essentially all data-loss recovery situations. You should consider your data utterly lost unless you have a backup from which you can restore.

Having said that, there may be options for you to recover, but every single action you take on the computer affected may make each recovery option less likely to succeed. Depending on how critical this data is, you may want to simply remove power from the computer now and image the disk drive to preserve possible forensic recovery. Other lower-impact but correspondingly-less-likely-to-succeed options may include duplicating the MDB file onto external storage.

This is only "Step 1". The next steps would involve analyzing the data you've preserved and trying to extract the data you need. With a disk image safely made, you may be able to boot the computer back up and check Volume Shadow Copy to see if there are any older revisions of the MDB file.

You need to weigh the time investment you're willing to make against the possibility that your data is simply gone. No recovery option is a guarantee and you could spend hours, days, or weeks on recovering the data that was deleted.

And having said all of that, not to needle, but having a backup routine could have avoided all of this.

Comment: In this same vein, depending on how desperate you are, there appears to be [an open source project for reading MDB files](http://mdbtools.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Also, it's unlikely you're using Access 2003, and even more unlikely that you haven't closed the database, but here's [a longshot answer from Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/209874) that includes a VB function which will read your database and recover some tables.